# DateTimePicker Editable Like TextBox in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, datetimepicker

I need a Winform component to act like a DateTimerPicker which is available in C# but I need it to be editable the same way as the TextBox component.

Is there something like that? or How can I  override DateTimerPicker to Act like that if that's possible?

Comment: have a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3455/Editable-Date-Picker

Comment: something like that, but in c# please

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ee0c5fbe-8d18-4899-8df2-46535b570bb4/how-to-create-a-nullable-and-editable-datetimepicker?forum=winforms