# How to allow insert date manually in Datetimepicker C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

How to allow insert date manually in Datetimepicker C#?
I tried to set `Custom Format`, but it does not work, I need that use able to change date manually.

Comment: May be you have find solution as mentioned in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165488/datetimepicker-editable-like-textbox-in-winform).

Comment: What's wrong with just setting its value property?

Comment: Your question is unclear... _”How to allow insert date manually in Datetimepicker C#?”_... in code you can change the `DateTimePickers.Value` with a `DateTime` object set to any date/time you like. In the UI you would simply change the date on the form. Is “manually” something else?  `CustomFormat` is used to format how the date time is displayed on the form, the user can change any value if they are displayed. Example, if the time is not displayed, then the user will not be able to change those values in the UI. That is where the `CustomFormat` helps display the date/time any way you need.